# regex to match the last five numbers in a row

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I need a regular expression to find **the last occurrence of 5 consecutive digits** in a string. This is what I have right now:

```
([0-9]{5})[a-zA-Z]*$
```

This only matches some of my test strings.

In a live environment the numbers will change, but for testing I expect to capture the substring `'12345'` in each of the test strings below:

> D012345
>
> D012345AS
>
> D012345RM-67
>
> D12345D
>
> 12345D67
>
> TEST-Str12345ing-rm6

Comment: Your examples seem to be confusing people.  In every one of them, the *last* run of five digits is also the *first* one.  If that's not always the case, you should improve the examples.

Comment: @AlanMoore Not entirely true. The first few examples are illustrative because many of the proposed solutions are selecting '01234' rather than '12345'. The regex must not only correctly select the last occurrence of a 5-digit substring, but also correctly select the _last 5 digits_ from a run of digits longer than 5.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: Okay, I see it.  And if the examples are correct, there's only one run of digits per string that might match, and all we have to worry about is matching the last five of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

Works w/ global flag, passes all tests. **No capture group required.**:

```
[0-9]{5}(?![0-9])(?!.*[0-9]{5})
```

Live example:
http://www.regexr.com/3c875

**Let's break this down:**

```
Match any instance of five digits
[0-9]{5}

But the instance cannot be immediately followed by another digit - this way,
we always get the last five in any group of consecutive numbers.
(?![0-9])

Lastly, make sure no further groups of consecutive numbers exist that have 
more than five digits.
(?!.*[0-9]{5})
```

Comment: Without the global flag, it [only captures the first group](https://regex101.com/r/lM6eL6/1).

Comment: This works as far as I'm testing it, but it's a lot less readable than anubhava's suggestion and seems based on regex101's reporting to be a good bit less efficient. Can you point to some counterexamples that break the other shorter suggestion?

Comment: anubhava's suggestion requires use of a capture group. You can consider my answer the best approach that does not require a caption group - if the OP is cool w/ the caption groups, he should go with anubhava's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
.*([0-9]{5})
```

to make sure you're matching last 5 continuous digits in the input. **Matched 5 digits are available in captured group #1.**

`.*` (greedy match) at start makes sure that we match very last 5 digits only.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sK6pJ5/4)

Comment: No, it doesn't - it's matching the first five digits, 0-4.

Comment: @anubhava Yeah and check the first line where in `D012345` it matches '01234', not '12345'. It seems to work for strings where there are distinct occurrences of 5-length digit sequences, but not correctly select the last 5 digits of a sequence of digits more than 5 long.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: ok check updated regex and demo now.

Comment: [I believe even `.*([0-9]{5})` will work without lookahead.](https://regex101.com/r/sK6pJ5/4)

Comment: @anubhava I think you are right and the leading greedy match is the secret sauce here. Good catch! I was beginning to think this wasn't solvable by regex. :P

Comment: Latest update matches lots of extra stuff. I have an answer below that works without a capture group.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart: As you can see from earlier edits I was also thinking on lookahead first but if just putting `.*` before gets the job done why worry about dual lookaheads,

Comment: Agreed - depends on whether the OP can use capture groups or not.

Comment: Well captured group is much more easily accessible and available than lookaheads.